# jackson 2 object to json ignore lazy loading

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, jackson, jackson2

I am using jackson 2 to parse an object to json format I am having problem when I parse lazy loading fields. I want to get a null reference if the object cannot be loaded.

How can I do that?

I want to discuss with you a solution and I want to know if there is a problem when I use it?

I have found that during parsing jackson uses getters method to get attributes So my solution is to modify the getters methods of lazy loading fields suppose that post is a lazy loaded field this is the getter of that fields

```
public Collection<Post> getPosts() {
        try{
            posts.size();
            return posts;
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
        return null;
    }
```

This solution is working fine but I don't know if it will cause future problems or not.
We should also use @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) to ignore null fields.

Comment: Why don't you just use `@JsonIgnore` annotation with this field?

Comment: if I use @JsonIgnore the fields will always be ignored. but what I want is that if the field can be loaded than parse it else don't.

Comment: In that case you can stick with using the solution you posted. I think there's no problem to use it.